# why is os.listdir not giving out anything?

Tags: python, operating-system, listdir

```
import os

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\jsun0011\Downloads\prank")
    print(file_list)
```

As I run the code, the output is supposed to display the files of the folder named "prank", yet nothings showing up. (in the pic)
[image]

Comment: "pic"? Did you forget to post a picture?

Comment: did you call `rename_files`? At least, empty list `[]` should be printed.

Comment: I cannot write an answer as I cannot test any code right now, but please check that S.O. link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python  as i think os returns an execution return code (success or fail), not a return value as subprocess.call does.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be fine and if you're not getting anything as output, there may be 2 cases:

> 1. prank folder doesn't contain anything, even in this case - It should've given empty list i.e.[]
> 2. you're not calling rename_files method anywhere (probably, this is your case), Kindly make a function call as defined below:

```
import os

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\jsun0011\Downloads\prank")
    print(file_list)

rename_files()
```